# Соглашение cookie при парсинге Python

Tags: python-3.x, requests, cookie, beautiful-soup

Добрый день при парсинге вылетает такое сообщение.
код:

```
import requests

from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
session = requests.Session()

link = 'https://www.vesseltracker.com/en/login.html?error=true'
user_fake = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {
    'user-agent':user_fake
}
data = {

    'username':'ник',
    'password': 'пароль'
}
reos = session.post(link,data=data,headers=header).text
provile_info = 'https://www.vesseltracker.com/'
progile = session.get(provile_info,headers=header).text
cookies_dict = [
    {'domain':key.domain,'name':key.name,'path':key.path,'value':key.value}
    for key in session.cookies
]
session2 = requests.Session()
for cookes in cookies_dict:
    session2.cookies.set(**cookes)
resp = session2.get(provile_info,headers=header)
print(resp.text)
```

Выход:

```
C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\nero\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Damir/IdeaProjects/parsership/shipparser.py
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><meta name="description" content="0"><meta name="author" content="vesseltracker.com"><meta name="_csrf" content="0"><meta name="_csrf_header" content="0"><title>Terrestrial &amp; Satellite AIS Tracking Service in Realtime - vesseltracker.com</title><!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics--><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1345977-1"></script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

</script><!-- google fonts--><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Open+Sans+Condensed-Light:300&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Bootstrap core CSS--><link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--Leaflet css--><link href="/webjars/leaflet/1.0.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--Flag css--><link href="/webjars/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--=link(rel="stylesheet",href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css",integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU",crossorigin="anonymous")--><!-- Custom styles for this template--><link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries--><!--if lt IE 9script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js')
script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js')
--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.css"></head><body class="home"><div class="body-overlay"></div><div role="navigation" id="main-navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"><img src="/assets/img/wave-hamburger.png" class="white"><img src="/assets/img/wave-hamburger-orange.png" class="orange"></button><a href="/" class="navbar-brand active animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span><img src="/assets/img/dragon.png" alt="" class="visible-xs-inline-block visible-sm-inline-block dragon-head-logo"><img src="/assets/img/logo-text-light.png" alt="" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span></a></div><div class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul class="nav navbar-nav text-uppercase"><li class="cta visible-xs-block">Learn more about our technology and shipping tools and<a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html">start your free trial now</a></li><li class="search visible-xs-block"><form id="mobileSearch" action="/en/vessels.html" method="get"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"><input id="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="term"><div class="input-group-addon"><a id="submitMobileSearch" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></div></div></div></form></li><li><a href="/en/products/" class="products animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span>Products</span></a></li><li><a href="/en/vessels.html" class="animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span>Vessels</span></a></li><li><a href="/en/ports.html" class="animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span>Ports</span></a></li><li><a href="/en/news.html" class="animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span>News</span></a></li><li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span>About</span><span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/en/static/about_vesseltracker.html">About</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="/en/community" class="animated-bg"><div class="background"></div><span>Community</span></a></li></ul><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase hidden-xs"><li class="search"><a href="#" id="navBarSrcBut" class="show"><span id="search-glass" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a><a href="#" id="navBarHideSrcBut" class="hidden"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></li><li class="login show"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal" class="btn">Log in</a></li><!-- todo re-enable language switcher once german verison is complete--><li class="dropdown language show"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><div class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></div><span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/en">English</a></li><li><a href="/de">German</a></li></ul><!--ul.dropdown-menuli
    if lang == "de"
        .flag-icon(class="flag-icon-de")
li
    if lang == "en"
        .flag-icon(class="flag-icon-gb")--></li><li class="cockpit-link show"><a id="cockpit-icon" data-trigger="manual" href="https://cockpit.vesseltracker.com" target="cockpit" _title="Open Cockpit" title="Looking for the Cockpit?" data-content="Click here to access our global vessel tracking tool &quot;Cockpit&quot;" data-placement="bottom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></a></li><li class="search-form hidden"><div class="background"></div><form action="/en/vessels.html" id="search-form" class="navbar-form navbar-left"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="navBarSrcInput" name="term" placeholder="IMO,MMSI,Name" class="form-control"></div></form></li></ul><div class="user visible-xs-block"><ul class="nav navbar-nav text-uppercase"><li class="login"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal" class="text-left">Log in</a><div class="lang"><a href="/en">EN</a> / <a href="/de">DE</a></div></li></ul></div></div></div></div><!--if currentUser == null.cta-banner.text-center.hidden-xs
    .container
        | Learn more about our technology and shipping tools and
        =' '
        a(href='/en/products/onlineAccounts.html') start your free trial now
        | !
--><div class="jumbotron lead-visual"><div class="video-bg"><video loop="" muted="" autoplay="" poster="/assets/video/vt_fp.jpg"><source src="/assets/video/vt_fp.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="/assets/video/vt_fp.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div><div class="container"><h1><!--small We build the future.--><br>The most comprehensive and accurate picture of global shipping</h1><a href="/en/products/dataServices.html" class="read-more btn btn-cta">Learn More</a></div></div><div class="cta-banner text-center visible-xs-block"><div class="container">Learn more about our technology and shipping tools and <a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html">start your free trial now</a> !</div></div><div class="what-we-do"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><h2>Fundamental data to drive trade flow algorithms, optimize maritime operations and increase market transparency.</h2><div class="separator-line"><div class="counterweight"></div></div><h3>TRULY GLOBAL COVERAGE THROUGH TERRESTRIAL AND SATELLITE AIS</h3><p>We provide multilingual support from four continents to ensure we are well positioned to install and maintain our AIS antennas in all commercial ports. We own and operate our global network of AIS antennas, meaning we can provide optimal data security, scope, reliability and quality.</p><p>Comprehensive satellite detected AIS data completes the picture by providing vessel movements and destination and ETA changes at sea.</p><h3>SHIP DATABASE – ShipDB</h3><p>Official industry partnerships ensure an accurate database of more than 600 fields of information on over 170,000 vessels. Characteristics, such as capacity, dimensions, management and ownership, classification, engine, equipment, and yard and build information delivered in multiple formats.</p><h3>FOCUSED ON YOU</h3><p>Over 10 years’ experience, delivering bespoke services via industry standards, to match your business needs.</p></div></div></div></div><div class="plans-intro"><div class="container"><h2 class="anchor"><small>Online Accounts</small><br>Choose the right plan for you</h2><div class="row hidden-xs"><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="plan-card free"><h4>Free</h4><p>Photographers, enthusiasts & hobbyists</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a></div></div><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="plan-card coastal"><h4>Coastal</h4><p>Ports, Terminals, Agents & Port Operations</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a></div></div><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="plan-card fleet"><h4>Fleet</h4><p>Vessel Owners, Managers, Brokers & Agents</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a></div></div><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="plan-card satellite"><h4>Satellite</h4><p>Global Traders & Analysts</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a></div></div></div></div><div id="plans-scroll-wrapper" class="visible-xs-block"><div id="plans-scrolled"><div class="plan-card free"><h4>Free</h4><p>Photographers, enthusiasts & hobbyists</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-cta">Learn More</a></div><div class="plan-card coastal"><h4>Coastal</h4><p>Ports, Terminals, Agents & Port Operations</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html#coastal" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html#coastal" class="btn btn-primary btn-cta">Learn More</a></div><div class="plan-card fleet"><h4>Fleet</h4><p>Vessel Owners, Managers, Brokers & Agents</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html#fleet" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html#fleet" class="btn btn-primary btn-cta">Learn More</a></div><div class="plan-card satellite"><h4>Satellite</h4><p>Global Traders & Analysts</p><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html#satellite" class="cover-link"></a><a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html#satellite" class="btn btn-primary btn-cta">Learn More</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cockpit-cta"><p><small>Vesseltracker Cockpit</small>Ad-free, fast and packed with features, Cockpit is the professional's vessel tracking solution.<br>Track specific vessels of interest or global shipping as a whole.</p><!--hidden on mobile because no mobile cockpit--><a href="/en/products/productsCockpit.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-cta hidden-xs">Learn More</a></div><div class="features"><div class="container"><h2 class="anchor"><small>DATA SERVICES</small><br>Customized real-time and historical data delivery to match your business needs</h2><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="feature-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="27" height="29" viewbox="0 0 27 29"><g><g transform="translate(-259 -2242)"><image width="27" height="29" transform="translate(259 2242)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"></image></g></g></svg><h4>Terrestrial and Satellite AIS</h4><a href="/en/products/dataServices.html"></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="feature-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="33" height="35" viewbox="0 0 33 35"><g><g transform="translate(-84 -1797)"><image width="33" height="35" transform="translate(84 1797)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACEAAAAjCAYAAAAaLGNkAAACpklEQVRYR+2Xz2sTQRTH35uY+ANTidhEMGKLeDGptMFcFJq2Cja9+6Mn8S8wWIOtQltzMK2lkj/BXjz4B2RRkKoIHvwRMQkBD6HSFprkELBCiU3nyawuJGGTzMZNrOBcdnd23rzPvPnum7cINe38m4KdsyPlt+dwq/adzHMr9lg5cf/z/KntMv8i+pgNTyYvurIyjrUxrdpXQXjjuSVAsAPBJiBkU0HXfSMQrdpXQZxR8td3iD9WI4HsRjLoVO9lW6v2VRDCWd+z/KC4Ji85X+s5Z47BqN3nu7n5MRHjxVd3a8c0s9ebE/vihQCHnZeyq12PLcCxUBi0a2M75ADExBhEy3Aq2K3rB71KboYQWHrUNSMDwhyBB3bfQKheJPTmaObDMIQMaO2YXQfRrxR7trHcK0Bt1j3ZxAXH145HwhPfIERQtUEEQ+mxo/hXIIRjIhK++e6E8CqFIUI+3Ir4am1WF+dHgLj/+4fEo9NPnpa0L1BsR8NI/NovnDUHYu6e+9Yd69ri3Nbx21PzhiAEpRkQIp90+c9OfXv3Pmo4EhrEwIviiR+l0ooGZMW9vWgDkun7FHSodlroK/OE1HZoECKdE/BIaswV8Coby4SWCOPAZfrSo93LpkGoZwrDCHCaBmYZERAyfaZBiJWIo5kD9TDAlc9B55KRPlMiYYY4/1gT/4VZ+XXIiFBPrP+2MDPjl21dfv+kyHB6tWMrQjUszLWFaNg9MblfrnaUREKkdNDFpDNmZvyK1WjtKIkCchBEs2pmbFdTMy5GRDGte3YIv4K0Xf61ebW/uboQ7QaonL8phEfJcSAypZ6ou7DfYq2qMfUoOxGZhhDMvu9wJyAy165OH/R4QyIvVYXeo+TWkeBAJyBWYw8PuUNhFDVoe/e/wWoq/2l/ArjmnbnQlLvYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></image></g></g></svg><h4>Ship Details, Characteristics, Specifications and Ownership</h4><a href="/en/products/shipDB.html"></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="feature-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="28" height="18" viewbox="0 0 28 18"><g><g transform="translate(-261 -2138)"><image width="28" height="18" transform="translate(261 2138)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"></image></g></g></svg><h4>Voyage Events and Analytics</h4><a href="/en/products/dataServices.html"></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="feature-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="28" height="27" viewbox="0 0 28 27"><g><g transform="translate(-260 -1919)"><image width="28" height="27" transform="translate(260 1919)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"></image></g></g></svg><h4>Ports and Terminals</h4><a href="/en/products/dataServices.html"></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="feature-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="28" height="33" viewbox="0 0 28 33"><g><g transform="translate(-261 -2020)"><image width="28" height="33" transform="translate(261 2020)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"></image></g></g></svg><h4>Weather Data and ETA Calculation</h4><a href="/en/products/dataServices.html"></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><div class="feature-box"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="45" height="45" viewbox="0 0 45 45"><g><g transform="translate(-78 -2345)"><image width="45" height="45" transform="translate(78 2345)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"></image></g></g></svg><h4>Maritime Reports</h4><a href="/en/products/maritimeReports.html"></a></div></div></div></div></div><div class="news"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="container"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="row"><a href="/en/Ships/Navin-Falcon-9492933.html"><div style="background-image: url('//cdn.vesseltracker.com/midres/943075.jpg')" class="fp-news-wrapper"></div></a><h2><small>Vessel of the day</small><br><a href="/en/Ships/Navin-Falcon-9492933.html">NAVIN FALCON</a>class="row">class="interm"></div><div class="interm"></div></div><div class="footer"><div class="logo"><img src="/assets/img/logo-text.png"></div><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3 location"><h4>Location + Contact</h4><p><div class="highlight">vesseltracker.com GmbH</div>Mundsburger Damm 14,<br>22087 Hamburg, Germany<br><br>+49 (0) 40 970 78610<br><a href="/en/contact.html">info@vesseltracker.com</a></p></div><div class="col-sm-3"><h4>About</h4><div class="list-group"><a href="/en/static/privacy_policy.html" class="list-group-item">Privacy Notice</a><a href="/en/static/terms.html" class="list-group-item">Terms of Use</a><a href="/en/static/imprint.html" class="list-group-item">Imprint</a><a href="/en/contact.html" class="list-group-item">Contact</a><a href="/en/static/Jobs.html" class="list-group-item">Jobs</a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><h4>Explore</h4><div class="list-group"><a href="/en/products/" class="list-group-item">Products</a><a href="/en/vessels.html" class="list-group-item">Vessels</a><a href="/en/ports.html" class="list-group-item">Ports</a><a href="/en/news.html" class="list-group-item">News</a><a href="/en/static/about_vesseltracker.html" class="list-group-item">About</a><a href="/en/community" class="list-group-item">Community</a></div></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><h4>Social</h4><a href="https://twitter.com/vesseltracker" target="_blank" class="icon icon-twitter"></a><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/vesseltracker" target="_blank" class="icon icon-linkedin"></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/vesseltracker" target="_blank" class="icon icon-facebook"></a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/vesseltrackerGermany" target="_blank" class="icon icon-youtube"></a><p>&nbsp;</p><p>© vesseltracker<script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script></p></div></div><div class="row footer-links"><div class="col-xs-12 text-center"></div></div></div></div><div id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="container"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</button><h2 class="modal-title">Log in</h2></div><div class="modal-body"><form action="/login.html" method="post" id="login-modal"><div class="container form"><input type="hidden" name="0" value="0"><div class="row"><div class="col"><input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="login-usr" name="username"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col"><input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="login-pass" name="password"></div></div><div class="row login-btn"><button type="submit" id="login-submit-modal-btn" class="btn btn-primary">LOG IN</button></div></div><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6"><label for="rememberMe">Remember me</label><input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="remember-me"></div><div class="col-xs-6 lost-pass">Lost password? <a href="/en/static/resetPassword.html">Reset</a></div></div></div></form></div><div class="modal-footer"><p>Don't have an account? <a href="/en/products/onlineAccounts.html">Register</a></p></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs"><div role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible"><h3 style="margin-top:1px">Phishing Attack Warning</h3> <p>There are some links in social media, promising a free trial for <b>vesseltracker.com</b>. The linked website is being used for phishing and attempting to collect login data from vesseltracker users.</p> <p>In order to keep you safe:</p> <ul> <li>Please make sure that you only enter your login data on the real websites <b>www.vesseltracker.com</b> or <b>cockpit.vesseltracker.com</b></li> <li>Make sure your browser shows a green lock in the address bar, indicating that it is a secure connection</li> <li>Should you have entered login data somewhere else already, please change your password on the real website. To do this, please log in at <b>www.vesseltracker.com</b>, click on your username and then on "My vesseltracker". There you will find the option to change the password</div></div></div></div></div></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="/webjars/leaflet/1.0.0/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/assets/js/lib.js"></script><script src="/assets/js/script.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="//cloudfront.loggly.com/js/loggly.tracker-latest.min.js" async=""></script><script>var _LTracker = _LTracker || [];
_LTracker.push({
    'logglyKey': 'acfd6b7f-0a41-4181-90b5-7ea7a36e5ef1',
    'sendConsoleErrors': true,
    'tag': 'website-errors'
});
</script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script><script>function deleteCookie(name, path){
    document.cookie=name+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path="+path;
}
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
cookie: {
    domain: 'vesseltracker.com',
    name: 'cookieconsent_status_3'
},
palette:{
    popup:{
        background: '#252e39'
    },
    button:{
        background: "#14a7d0"
    }
},
type: "opt-in",
content: {
    href: "https://www.vesseltracker.com/en/static/privacy_policy.html",
    message: "We use cookies to improve your experience. We take your privacy very seriously. Please see our privacy policy for details and any questions.",
    deny: "Opt-out"
},
revokable:true,
onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
    var type = this.options.type;
    var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
    if (type == 'opt-in') {
        if (didConsent){
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', 'UA-1345977-1');
        } else {
            deleteCookie("_gid","/");
            deleteCookie("_ga","/");
            deleteCookie("_gat_gtag_UA_1345977_1","/");
        }
    }
}

});</script></body></html>
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Так а в чём проблема-то?

Comment: в том что при попытке получения html кода приходит вот это, как сделать чтоб я код получил и из него взять тексты.

Comment: Ну приходит и приходит, в чём проблема-то с этим?

Comment: так мне то код нужен

Comment: Ну вот перед вами html-код из ответа, в чём проблема?

Comment: этож не код страницы

Comment: Это код главной страницы сайта, что не так?

Comment: к примеру мне нужно название танкера а тут его нет это сообщение везде появляется

Comment: нет там совсем другое любую ссылку этого сайта везде такой ответ

Comment: Значит изучайте через мониторинг сети, какая последовательность запросов к сайту приводит к появлению названия танкера, и повторяйте её в своём python-коде. При чём тут показанный в вопросе код и при чём тут cookie?

Comment: хорошо я хотел бы получить код страницы можете помочь мне.

Comment: https://www.vesseltracker.com/en/news/category/piracy.html вот на этой странице нужно взять инфу.

Comment: Извиняюсь, вы правы это и есть код страницы я не заметил что все ушло в длинную строку.